# Detail of operation of !function() { return false; } ()

Tags: javascript, function

```
!function() { return false; } ()
```

I'm aware why you might write something like this, but I have a question about the way it works.  As I understand it, the exclamation mark does two things:

1. It acts on `function() { return false; }`, changing it into an expression
2. It also acts on the result of the executed function, so that the whole line evaluates to `true`

So my questions are:

1. Is this the correct explanation?
2. If it is correct, then since `()` binds more tightly than `!`, how did the first part (the change of the function itself into an expression) happen?  Why doesn't the exclamation mark act on the whole line throughout?

Comment: it would appear so: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: may be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It doesnt "change" it. It makes so when the parser goes through the "function" bit it goes expecting an expression, so the "function" is parsed as part of an (possibly anonymous) function expression instead of as a function statement.

2) It *is* acting on the whole line. If you look at the precedences, as suggested by jbabey, you see that function call binds more tightly then the negation operator so the whole like is evaluated as

```
! ((function(){})());
```

Or in a similar, perhaps more readable version:

```
var f = function(){ ... };
! (f());
```

Comment: Part 1 of your answer has made this much clearer for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

according to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the `function` declaration (which is shorthand for `new Function`) would happen first, the function call `()` would happen second, and the negation `!` would happen last.

edit for clarity: You could rewrite that one line as this to accomplish the same thing:

```
// declare an anonymous function and assign it to the myFunc variable
var myFunc = function () { 
    return false; 
};

// execute the function and store it's return value (false) in returnValue
var returnValue = myFunc();

// negate the return value (true)
var output = !returnValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did understand this part and mentioned in my question that () binds more tightly than !. I was confused by how the other side effect came about.